# Visual Studio: How can I change the color of the code outlining gutter?

Tags: visual-studio

How can I change the color of the gutter to the right of the line numbers?  This space typically contains code outlining expanders/collapsers.  I don't see an obvious display item for it in Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors > Text Editor.

It is the part I have outlined in red below.

[image]